# WSUS: which product should be selected to cater for Windows 10 22H2 updates?

Tags: group-policy, wsus

I have a WSUS server running for some time on Windows Server, catering for the needs of my Windows 10 Professional clients. All clients were on version 21H2 up to some days ago. In WSUS under products I had only "Windows 10, version 1903 or later" selected. Not sure if it was the correct one, however I have been receiving updates just fine for my clients in the last year.

Since 21H2 is going EOL, in WSUS I approved the Windows 10 22H2 enablement package, a couple of days go. Things seemed fine, already most of the clients have updated without a hitch.

What I do not understand is that I am not offered any cumulative updates for 22H2 in WSUS, like I used to get with when my clients were on 21H2. In the following screenshot notice that there is not a single reference to **22H2** (apologies if it's all Greek to you):
[image: Screenshot from the WSUS panel]

Should I select a different product in WSUS and, if so, which? Or, perhaps, I'm missing out something different altogether?

Output of `wmic qfe get hotfixid,installedon`:

```
HotFixID   InstalledOn
KB5022502  2/16/2023
KB4562830  3/2/2021
KB4577586  4/5/2021
KB4580325  3/3/2021
KB4589212  4/5/2021
KB4598481  3/2/2021
KB5000736  8/19/2021
KB5003791  12/31/2021
KB5012170  2/9/2023
KB5015684  5/26/2023
KB5026361  5/10/2023
KB5006753  11/12/2021
KB5007273  12/15/2021
KB5011352  2/19/2022
KB5011651  4/28/2022
KB5014032  6/2/2022
KB5014035  6/30/2022
KB5014671  7/19/2022
KB5015895  9/1/2022
KB5016705  10/12/2022
KB5018506  12/8/2022
KB5020372  1/3/2023
KB5022924  3/15/2023
KB5023794  4/13/2023
KB5025315  5/10/2023
KB5005699  9/17/2021
```

Comment: `Or, perhaps, I'm missing out something different altogether?` You need to start by specifying what updates are installed. You can do that by including the text output of the command: `wmic qfe get hotfixid,installedon`

Comment: Edited the OP to include the information.

Comment: KB5026361 is installed. That is the cumulative update for Windows 10 22H2 for May 2023.  Therefore, it appears to be updating as expected. You may want to elaborate on what you mean by "not offered any cumulative updates for 22H2". Try specifying what you are doing, what the expected result is, and what occurs instead. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-9-2023-kb5026361-os-builds-19042-2965-19044-2965-and-19045-2965-3edafffe-c3cc-4010-af43-2097c84c9437

Comment: My WSUS "All Updates" panel included cumulative updates mentioning 21H2 only: KB5026361 was included (and approved) with the title "2023-05 Cumulative update for Windows 10 Version **21H2** for x64-based systems". But there was no separate "2023-05 Cumulative update for Windows 10 Version **22H2** for x64-based systems" listed, like I used to see in the past, when I had a mixture of 2xHy systems running. Shouldn't that be llisted for me to approve?

Comment: Yes, there is a KB5026361 for both 21H2 and 22H2. There are also logs on the client endpoints where you can verify that the updates are being downloaded and installed from the location that you specify (presumably the WSUS server). https://imgur.com/a/d5cBQto

Comment: I've edited the OP to include a screenshot of my own WSUS panel. In your own screenshot there are clearly different updates to approve for the **same Windows KB**, whereas in my case 22H2-updates are nowhere to be found.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the server would have not pulled down that one update during the previous synchronization. The screen shot is filtered. You may have better results using the Search feature for KB5026361.  See: https://imgur.com/a/0rIJ3IU

Comment: Very interesting; did a search for it and [there it was](https://imgur.com/a/YLr2kZB). Furthermore, getting a report for its x64 22H2 variant I can see that all my clients carry a "Not Applicable" status for it. It comes logical then that the "All updates" pane did not show it, since my filter was for "failed or needed" updates (switching to "any" shows the 22H2 update just fine). So, you were spot on that the server downloads it alright. Most likely will have to wait for the June patch Tuesday to check how it behaves.